# How to use multiple variables.less files for subpages?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to setup my site to use multiple themes based on which subfolder you're on. For example, On the root index.html file I'm using the default variables.less file, but if I click on the "Football" link, it takes you to another subpage in the site which has a different color scheme using "variables-football.less", thus overriding the root variables file.

- css
- fonts
- img
- js
- less

  - bootstrap.less (imports variables.less)
- index.html (includes bootstrap.css)
- football

  - css
  - img
  - less

    - variables-football.less (custom subpage styles)
  - index.html (includes root level bootstrap.css)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jeff

Comment: simple, don't reference the variables.less file in the football index.html, only reference the theme-football.less

Comment: The variables.less file is referenced in the bootstrap.css file which is included site-wide. I would rather not pull it out of there and include it separately.